# Enlarging text while having line numbers enabled covers the view of the numbers?

Tags: emacs

> Enlarging text while having line numbers enabled covers the view of the numbers?

I've enabled line numbers globally by adding `(global-linum-mode t)` to init.el.

Zooming in on text using the `C-x C-+` keybinding results in the behavior seen below, which is not satisfactory.

What can I do to fix this? Are their working alternatives?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this problem, using library [`zoom-frm.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/zoom-frm.el) (see also Emacs Wiki page [Set Fonts](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SetFonts)).

But vanilla Emacs clearly has another bug, in that enlarging the text by scaling enlarges the horizontal space used for the line numbers (good), but shrinking the text then does not shrink that space used for line numbers (bad). I've just now filed Emacs bug #[24164](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24164) for this.